# How many ways to place $m$ labelled balls into $n$ labelled boxes such that at least one box has more than $k$ balls

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

There are **$n^m$** ways to place $m$ labelled balls into $n$ labelled boxes with no constraints.

When it comes to the problem such that at least one box has more than $k$ balls.

My thought was

Step 1.  choose $k+1$ balls to form a big ball gives $\binom{m}{k+1}$ ways

step 2.  solve the unconstraint problem to place $m-k$ labelled balls(1 big ball + $m-(k+1)$ original balls) into $n$ labelled boxes, which comes out $n^{m-k}$ ways

put thogether using product rule we have 
$$\binom{m}{k+1}n^{m-k}$$
ways.

Validate with an example below the above was not correct.

Example with $m=4; n=2, k=2;$ based on the above ,$\binom{4}{3}2^{2}  =16$ but acutually we only have 10 diffent ways as $$(1234,0)(0,1234)(123,4)(4,123),(124,3)(3,124)(134,2)(2,134)(234,1)(1,234)$$

Could anybody help find where was wrong and give a correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're over-counting. For instance, in the example that you show, the distribution $(1234,0)$ is actually counted $4$ times as there are $4$ different ``big balls'' that could have given this distribution. In order to solve this, use inclusion-exclusion. For instance, for $i\in[n]$, let $A_i$ denote the set of distributions in which bucket $i$ gets at least $k+1$ balls. If $A$ denotes the set of distributions in which some bucket gets at least $k+1$ balls, then $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Now, inclusion-exclusion tells you that
$$
|A|=\sum_{S\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|S|-1}\biggl|\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i\biggr|
$$
To compute this, for any $S\subseteq[n]$, $\bigcap_{i\in S} A_i$ is the set of all distributions in which bucket $i$ gets at least $k+1$ balls for all $i\in S$. Let's try to count $|A_i|$ first. First, we could decided that bucket $i$ has $\ell$ balls where $k+1\leq \ell\leq n$, choose which $\ell$ balls go into bucket $i$, and then distribute the remaining balls amongst the rest of the bins. Thus, $|A_i|=\sum_{\ell=k+1}^n{n\choose \ell}(m-1)^{n-\ell}$. Similarly, for $S\subseteq[n]$, we can count $\bigl|\bigcap_{i\in S}A_i\bigr|$ by first choosing how many balls go into each bucket indexed by $S$, so we select $\ell_i\geq k+1$ where $\ell=\sum_{i\in S}\ell_i\leq n$, choose which balls go into these buckets, and then distribute the remaining $n-\ell$ balls into the remaining buckets. Thus,
$$
\biggl|\bigcap_{i\in S} A_i\biggr|=\sum_{\substack{\ell=\sum_{i\in S}\ell_i\leq n:\\ \ell_i\geq k+1}}{n!\over (n-\ell)!\prod_{i\in S}\ell_i!}(m-|S|)^{n-\ell}.
$$
In conclusion,
$$
|A|=\sum_{r=0}^m(-1)^{r-1}{m\choose r}\sum_{\substack{\ell=\ell_1+\cdots+\ell_r\leq n:\\ \ell_i\geq k+1}}{n!\over \ell_1!\ell_2!\cdots\ell_r!(n-\ell)!}(m-r)^{n-\ell}.
$$
This is quite a messy answer, though.

Another way to approach this problem may be by induction. In particular, let $B_{n,m}$ denote the number of ways to distribute $n$ balls into $m$ buckets so that some bucket gets more than $k$ balls. By breaking into cases depending on how many balls bucket $m$ gets, we can write
$$
B_{m,n}=\sum_{\ell=0}^k{n\choose \ell}B_{m-1,n-\ell}+\sum_{\ell=k+1}^n{n\choose\ell}(m-1)^{\ell-1}.
$$
Unfortunately, this does not seem to lead to a nice closed form either, but would allow you to efficiently compute these numbers by dynamic programming if you so wished.

As a last thought, I highly doubt that there will be a nice closed form for this problem. For instance, if $n\leq k$, then $B_{m,n}=0$, if $n=k+1$, then $B_{m,n}=m$, and if $n>mk$, then $B_{m,n}=m^n$. I don't see how a ``nice'' function could satisfy these constraints.